How to perform the OFDM frequency-domain oversampling in time domain
Generally, Oversampling in OFDM that is implemented by padding zeros before the ifft corresponds to oversampling in time domain.
For example, having the input signal x with size Nx1, to perform frequency-domain oversampling with factor u = 2, we start padding the signal x with (u-1)*N zeros, then perform ifft operation to get the output y with size uN x 1.
That means we can perform the above process in time domain by performing ifft for the signal x and then oversample the resulted time-domain signal to produce the same signal y. However I couldn't get the signal y using the oversampling in the time domain. How can we do that in MATLAB or any other simulator.

"the signal y should be identical to y_o" no: y_o is linear-interpolated, y is not.

@AlexTP So how can we perform the time-domain oversampling to produce the identical signal of y ?  The above code is an example I used based on my understanding.

The interpolation done via FFT is convoluting with a sinc, which is the inverse fourier transform of the windowing (which corresponds to the zeropadding in your question) in frequency domain. So, inverse transform rectangular window and convolve the sinc with the original time signal having zero inserted between its two samples.

@AlexTP  So, 1) I need to upsample the signal y_2 by inserting zero between each two samples, but I didn't get the steps  2) and 3)  which are inverse the transform rectangular window and convolve the sinc with the original time signal. Could you please write it down with details as an answer? Thank you

@AlexTP I also added its calculation using sinc

I think that you are on the right path. What you are missing is considering the fact that in the discrete-time domain, the kernel of interpolation is the Dirichlet kernel (aliased sinc). Moreover, in order to perform a zero-phase interpolation, the zero-padding in the frequency must be happen in the middle. Otherwise, you should consider phase shifting the signal. The MATLAB code below shows how to do time-domain interpolation
N = 5;
u = 2;

x = rand(N,1);

% Zero-padding in frequency domain
xpad = [x(1:(N+1)/2);zeros((u-1)*N,1);x((N+1)/2+1:end)];
xi_freq = ifft(xpad);

% Interpolation in time domain
% Dirichlet kernel
dsinc = diric(2*pi*(0:u*N-1)/(u*N),N)/u;
% Circular convolution
xi_time = cconv(upsample(ifft(x),u),dsinc,u*N);


fprintf("L-inf of error = %.2e\n",max(abs(xi_freq-xi_time)))

figure
tiledlayout(2,2)

nexttile
stem(real(xi_freq),"filled")
nexttile
stem(imag(xi_freq),"filled")
nexttile
stem(real(xi_time),"filled")
nexttile
stem(imag(xi_time),"filled")
```


Could you please continue the MATLAB code to include the case where the zero padding is placed at the end (instead at the middle) of the frequency-domain signal? .. Thank you
